# Spring Boot console password

Tags: spring-boot

I use Spring Boot and I have read that a default should be printed out at log file or console - but there is nothing in my log.
I use putty to connect and the connection is find but I dont know the credentials (password). Is there any hint I can do in order to get it work?

**[EDIT]**
I also added this to lines to my application.properties file:

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=secret
```

but with no effect.

Log file screenshot:

[image]

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartinnotec.accounting</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartinnotec-accounting-frontend</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**[EDIT]**

If I remove the both annotations than a password is printed out at start time. 
My problem is, that I need the Beans defined in this class.
Actually I dont know what to do?
Is it possible to enable web security and also to print out the password?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] restEndpointsToSecure;
@Autowired
private XAuthTokenConfigurer xAuthTokenConfigurer;

static {
    restEndpointsToSecure = new String[7];
    ...
}

@Autowired(required = true)
private UserService userService;

public WebSecurityConfig() {
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    final String[] restEndpointsToSecure = WebSecurityConfig.restEndpointsToSecure;
    for (final String endpoint : restEndpointsToSecure) {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/" + endpoint + "/**").hasRole(UserRoleEnum.USER.toString());
    }

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterAfter(csrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    xAuthTokenConfigurer.setDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    final SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter = xAuthTokenConfigurer;
    http.apply(securityConfigurerAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(new CustomUserDetailsService(userService));
}

@Bean
public CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter csrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter() {
    return new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter();
}

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[WebSecurityConfig]";
}
}
```

Comment: you use putty to connect to what? you don't know the credentials of what? how do you actually use spring boot?

Comment: Do you have spring security in your pom/classpath? You could manuallly set the security.user.name=admin and security.user.password=secret for example. This eliminates the need to find the credentials.

Comment: This might help [Getting Started : Spring Security](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/04/how-to-configure-spring-security-with-spring-boot.html)

Comment: show us your pom.xml.  Do you have spring-boot-starter-security dependency ?

Comment: if you add security credentials in application.properties, default password will not get printed in console, you would use those credentials then.

Comment: I added this three parameters in application.properties: 
shell.ssh.port=8094
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=userpw but with no effect, I can not login with user/userpw

Comment: Colud you send a log output with running your app `--debug` parameter?

Comment: Remove property parameters. A random password string should be printed as an INFO log. If you override this it will not be printed. And property file is not the only way to set it up. There are 4,5 ways and some can override the property file as well for example if you use cmd parameter to set the password. try the minimal/default config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use putty to connect

I think you are looking for a remote shell connection to actuator endpoints. If so, you should add the following into your dependency tree.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Spring will print the default remote shell password in the console:

```
Using default password for shell access: 9b1abe6e-4ec0-4dca-a97a-fed2dadf1837
```

To override the default username/password, add followings into your `application.properties` file or `yml`.

```
management.shell.auth.simple.user.name=username
management.shell.auth.simple.user.password=password
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add 'Spring Security' to your project, all sensitive endpoints exposed over HTTP will be protected. By default ‘basic’ authentication will be used with the username user and a generated password (which is printed on the console when the application starts), just like

> Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35

Then you can you this password to login.

But you need to ensure that the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security` category is set to log INFO messages, otherwise the default password will not be printed.

Or you can change the password by providing a `security.user.name` for username and `security.user.password` for password, then the default password will not get printed in console.